# reportviewer How to make rectangle background transparent

Tags: c#, reporting-services, colors, reportviewer

I have 3 rectangles that differ from each other in opacity. The base color is same for all of them. For eg: the base color could be Red and the three rectangles would have the following colors: Red, Red (opacity: 55), Red (opacity: 135).

I tried setting the `Background Color` of the rectangle but it seems I cannot change the transparency of a rectangle. Is there a workaround for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is a limitation of reportviewer. Opacity values can be given to only gauges and graphs. Shapes and fonts do not accept opacity values. 
A close workaround to this is to add the opacity value to RGB. For example: if I want to generate a color in`RGBA as (255,0,0,160)` , I should add `255-160=95` to the values of G and B to get a color close to my needs. Therefore the color turns out to be `(255,95,95)`. It is not the exact color but it is close. I tried this for red, blue and green colors since those are the only colors I need.

I hope this helps someone.